# MYSQL Update Single column with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

There is this table "`Trade`" with column "`call`",Call contains `values(C,P)` when loaded from CSV
I want to update Trade from java program such that `if call='C' then call='CE'` and

`if call='P' then call='PE'`

I figured out this can be done using 2 queries.like this

```
update Trade set call='CE' where call='C';

update Trade set call='PE' where call='P';
```

is there anyway this can be done in single query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CALL` is a reserved keyword and needs to be escaped.

```
UPDATE  Trade
SET     `CALL` = CASE   WHEN `Call` = 'C' THEN 'CE'
                        WHEN `Call` = 'P' THEN 'PE'
                    ELSE `CALL` END
WHERE   `CALL` IN ('C','P')
```

Comment: you need to escape `CALL` since it is a reserved keyword. `:D`

Answer (score 5):

The shortest solution I see:

```
UPDATE Trade 
SET call = CONCAT(call,'E')
WHERE call IN ('C', 'P');
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this in one query, using the `CASE` expression. Something like this:

```
update Trade 
set call = CASE 
             WHEN callputtype='C' THEN 'CE' 
             WHEN callputtype='P' THEN 'PE' 
           END
where callputtype IN ('c', 'P');
```